# jQuery - Check if any specific radio buttons are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

**jQuery**

```
$('input').change(function() {

  $('input:radio').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.answer-detail').show();

  $(this).next('label').addClass('correct');

  var correctAnswers = ("#answer1d", "#answer2c", "#answer3c");

  if (!$(correctAnswers).is(":checked")) {
    alert('Nothing is checked!');
  } else {
    alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
  }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<p>1: <span>What colour is the snowflake?</span></p>
<input class="answer" id="answer1a" type="radio" name="answer1" value="answer1a" /><label for="answer1a">Monochrome</label>
<input class="answer" id="answer1b" type="radio" name="answer1" value="answer1b" /><label for="answer1b">White</label>
<input class="answer" id="answer1c" type="radio" name="answer1" value="answer1c" /><label for="answer1c">Pantone 000C</label>
<input class="answer" id="answer1d" type="radio" name="answer1" value="answer1d" /><label for="answer1d">None of the above</label>
```

I want to check if any of the 'correctAnswers' checkboxes are checked.

At the moment if I selected 'answer1d' it returns:-

```
alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
```

Any idea how I can loop through each answer and see if either are checked?

Comment: try to use [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `correctAnswers` to an array of `id` attributes, then use the [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if the checked element's `id` is in the array:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/chjdcqoh/)

```
var correctAnswers = ["answer1d", "answer2c", "answer3c"];

if (correctAnswers.indexOf(this.id) > -1) {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
} else {
  alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter checked elements along with `.length` to get checked elements count:

```
var correctAnswers = ("#answer1d,#answer2c,#answer3c");
if(!$(correctAnswers).filter(':checked').length) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
```